# Adjective phrase for a list of something

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms, adjective-phrases

I wrote:

> After selecting a filter designed for a specific website (e.g. Wikipedia), click on 'Sample article' on the top corner of the **filter list** to load a sample page for testing the filter.

by "filter list" I mean this part, which is a list of filters:

[image]

Now, what is called? "Filter List" or "Filters List" or ...?

Comment: 'Filter' is not an adjective in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the box with a **list** of websites might be call a

> **Filters** list

this is because the designation **Filters** is already given to the box.  Usually in **technical writing**, it is best to conform to a **strict naming convention** so the user can follow in a **consistent** way across a **range of topics**.  This way of writing can be very different to **ordinary prose** writing.

What the popup / dropdown box (depending on implementation) is representing is not a **list of filters** *per se* but a **configuration of filters**.  It might be better to refer to it as

> Filters configuration menu
>   Filters configuration box
>   Filters box

since the frame of reference is the **box** and not so much the **list** in your directions

> click on "Sample article" on the top right corner of the **Filters configuration box** to load a sample page for testing the filter.

Comment: Thank you, however I didn't get why should I use **configuration box**? **box** seems enough. In fact, the user select a filter from this list and apply it on the page. it is also possible that new filters be added later to this list (however not via this box)

Comment: Also, what if I haven't given a name to the list? then is it filter list or filters list?

Comment: For only the list, it could be either **filter list** or **list of filters**

Comment: @Ahmed In the presentation of the list *of things*, there will be a **box** (due to UI functionality, and there will probably be many different **boxes** in the UI), and the box will usually have a **title** (best practice is that the title is unique within the application), whatever the title is is how that area should be referenced to the user (so there is no ambiguity). In your example, the **Filters** box is composed of a user specified **website list** and **four buttons**: Edit, Sample article, Apply, and Reset which may be enabled or disabled depending on application state.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either 'Filter list' or 'List of Filters'.
Dictionary:

> **list** noun
>
> 1. a series of names or other items written or printed together in a meaningful grouping or sequence so as to constitute a record: *a list of members.*

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/list

When you say *a list of* something, you use the plural form. When you use it as a suffix or a single word, you use singular:

> hit-list
>   blacklist
>   wish list

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: @NathanTuggy added dictionary reference.

Comment: @cst1992 but your dictionary reference does not explain *why* filter**s** list is not correct